# MVC 3.0 Editing a variable length list and using the PRG pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, variable-length

I created  a view with a variable length list as described here: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/.

I am trying to use the PRG pattern with action filters as described at point 13 here: http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx.

I have an Edit action:

```
    [HttpGet, ImportModelStateFromTempData]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
    }
```

And the post action:

```
    [HttpPost, ExportModelStateToTempData]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        if (!TryUpdateModel<CategoryEntity>(category, formCollection))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = id });
        }

        // succes, no problem processing this...
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = id });
    }
```

All works fine including validation and error messages.

The only problem I have is that newly added items and deleted items (client side deleted/added) are not preserved after the redirect. I am trying to find a way to update my model after the redirect with the new items. I changed the ImportModelStateFromTempData attribute to use the OnActionExecuting override instead of the OnActionExecuted override to have the ModelState available in the action but I don't see a clean way to update my model from the passed in ModelState.

Changed ImportModelStateFromTempData:

```
public class ImportModelStateFromTempData : ModelStateTempDataTransfer
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ModelStateDictionary modelState = filterContext.Controller.TempData[Key] as ModelStateDictionary;

        if (modelState != null)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Merge(modelState);
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //ModelStateDictionary modelState = filterContext.Controller.TempData[Key] as ModelStateDictionary;

        //if (modelState != null)
        //{
        //    //Only Import if we are viewing
        //    if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
        //    {
        //        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Merge(modelState);
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        //Otherwise remove it.
        //        filterContext.Controller.TempData.Remove(Key);
        //    }
        //}
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Any input on this is much appreciated, thanks.

Harmen

UPDATE: Thought I might add some more of my (pseudo) code to make it more clear:

```
public class CategoryEntity
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public IEnumerable<CategoryLocEntity> Localized;
}

public class CategoryLocEntity
{
    public int CategoryId;
    public int LanguageId;
    public string LanguageName;
    public string Name;
}
```

My Edit view:

```
@model CategoryEntity

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Views.Category.Edit;
}

<h2>@Views.Category.Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#addItem').click(function () {
            var languageId = $('#languageId').val();
            var index = $('#editor-rows').children().size() - 1;
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href + '?languageId=' + languageId + '&index=' + index,
                cache: false,
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                },
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#editor-rows').append(html);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

        $("a.removeItem").live("click", function () {
            $(this).parents("div.editor-row:first").remove();
            return false;
        });
    });

--></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Views.Shared.Category</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <div id="editor-rows">
            <div class="editor-row">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, Views.Shared.NameEnglish)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>
            </div>

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Localized.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Localized[i], "_CategoryLoc", null, null)
            }
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label"></div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("languageId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LanguageSelectList)
            @Html.ActionLink(Views.Category.AddNewLanguage, "AddNewLanguage", null, new { id = "addItem" })
        </div>

        <p class="clear">
            <input type="submit" value="@Views.Shared.Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink(Views.Shared.BackToList, "Index")
</div>
```

Editor template for the CategoryLocEntity:

```
@model CategoryLocEntity

<div class="editor-row">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LanguageId)
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LanguageName, Model.LanguageName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        <a href="#" class="removeItem">@Views.Shared.Remove</a>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, however it does not work in my case, because my collection indices is not sequential (I'm using additional .index field to do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution (probably not the most elegant one but it works for me). I created my own ModelStateValueProvider to be used with UpdateModel. The code is based on the DictionaryValueProvider. See http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/2.6.4-mono-.net-core/System.Web/System/Web/Mvc/DictionaryValueProvider%601.cs.htm.

```
public class ModelStateValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    HashSet<string> prefixes = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary;

    public ModelStateValueProvider(ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary)
    {
        if (modelStateDictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("modelStateDictionary");

        this.modelStateDictionary = modelStateDictionary;

        FindPrefixes();
    }

    private void FindPrefixes()
    {
        if (modelStateDictionary.Count > 0)
            prefixes.Add(string.Empty);

        foreach (var modelState in modelStateDictionary)
            prefixes.UnionWith(GetPrefixes(modelState.Key));
    }

    public bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix)
    {
        if (prefix == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("prefix");
        }

        return prefixes.Contains(prefix);
    }

    public ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
    {
        if (key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        return modelStateDictionary.ContainsKey(key) ? modelStateDictionary[key].Value : null;
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> GetPrefixes(string key)
    {
        yield return key;
        for (int i = key.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            switch (key[i])
            {
                case '.':
                case '[':
                    yield return key.Substring(0, i);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ModelStateValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
{
    public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        return new ModelStateValueProvider(controllerContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState);
    }
}
```

I use it in de Edit (Get) action like:

```
[HttpGet, ImportModelStateFromTempData]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  var category = new CategoryEntity(id);
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {    
     TryUpdateModel<CategoryEntity>(category, 
         new ModelStateValueProviderFactory().GetValueProvider(ControllerContext));
  }
  return View(category);
}
```

Looking forward to your comments...